# Problem with Flex unit testing in IntelliJ

Tags: apache-flex, unit-testing, intellij-idea

I have some problems running  FlexUnit tests in IntelliJ.

Every time I execute test, Internet Explorer (which is not even set as default browser) pops up and blocks unit test, i.e. blocks it as add so I must allow access through that dumb top bar and then another confirmation and then finally test runs. Is there any way to reconfigure it to another browser or to run it some other way so I just hit the Run button on Idea and I can see results right away?

Thank you for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are using Windows have a look at the first comment by Alexander Doroshko in this bug report: http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issue/IDEA-49795

> Current behavior:
>
> - if 'Use system default browser' is selected at Settings | Web Browsers | Default Web Browser then swf/html is started in default OS application (either default browser of standalone Flash player)
> - if default browser is overridden in IDEA then it is always used both for swf/html.
>
> It would be more convenient if standalone Flash player is used for swfs independently of this setting as soon as it is OS default program for sfws.

I recommend to configure the stand alone flashplayer executable for executing unit tests. As you can also see from the report this has been improved in IDEA 10.